# Silverlight SQL Help & Understanding

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, sql-server-2008, ria

I'm coding a project for my degree and I'm stuck on Silverlight and SQL, once I get a simple query executed through this I can then work on coding the rest of my program with ease. I would really like simple answers. I have played around with WCF RIA, domain services.

I can not get anything to work. I have created an ADO.NET Entity model with Silverlight and SQL Express 2008. I have created a domain Service and selected my required table. Yet I can not get it to work.

Can anyone provide simple basic instructions and if possible with code how to pull data from a database on the server side and allow it to be presented on the client silverlight application. I just need the ability to use data for creating a login/booking system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Soon you will sell your soul to MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/using-wcf-ria-services/#Exercise2

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/helpercoil/archive/2010/09/19/introduction-to-silverlight-and-wcf-ria-tutorial-part-3-domain-data-source.aspx

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/wcf-ria-services-hands-on-lab/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WCF RIA. I just use a regular WCF service running via an ASP.NET website. My Silverlight application calls regular methods on this service and those methods then use ADO.NET to interact with the SQL on the server-side. Using WCF RIA may complicate things if you're just starting out.

The web service methods I have written expose collections of POCOs that are created from my database records. Adding the service reference to my Silverlight application then generates the client-side versions of these data types, ready for consumption by my UI components.

Comment: Hi, I have also used plain regular WCF with ASP.NET, I have this method currently set on my project. Is there any possibility you can explain how to just retrieve a simple amount of data from a database.